# Mocking class method using jest in javascript

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a class in which under render it calls a function that reads a value from `this`. Is there any way to mock that function so that test can run successfully.

```
Class Car extends PureComponent{
    readFromThis = () => {
        const helper = this.helper;
        return helper.key();
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>{this.readFromThis()}</div>)
    }
};
export { Car };
```

Here `helper` is undefined so helper.key() logs error and test fails to run with error --> `cannot read property key of undefined`. How to mock `readFromThis()` so that a custom implementation can be done.

Answer (score 0):

For mocking a method like this, I believe you can do the following:

```
const readFromThisSpy = jest.spyOn(Car.prototype, 'readFromThis').mockImplementation(() =>
  {
    // Your mock implementation here
  });
```

And then you can tear down that spy in the `afterAll()` or `afterEach()` function by doing the following:

```
readFromThisSpy.mockRestore();
```

Comment: `Cannot spy the readFromThis property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`